# find string that the second string is 9 using R

Tags: r

I have a list of numbers and I want to find  numbers which their second string is 9. the grep() code find any number that has 9 but I am looking for a code that find number that second string is 9. so the below returns:

```
p <- c(34405, 09098424, 6908347, 8900333, 453434)
grep(9, p)
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

I am looking for something that return:

```
[1] 2 3 4
```

Thanks
Majran

Comment: `grep("^.9", p)` ... `period` is a regex wildcard.

Comment: There could be a general difficulty since the OP seems to be storing `p` as numeric. If this is true, leading zeros will be lost - even in the case of a type conversion with `as.numeric()`. The only remedy I can think of, besides the obvious approach to store the data directly as characters, is to provide additional information on the total number of digits for each entry.

Comment: ...I obviously meant to say "type conversion with `as.character()`".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `substr` to extract the 2nd digit and check whether (`==`) that is equal to 9, get the numeric index by wrapping with `which`.

```
which(substr(p,2,2)=="9")
#[1] 2 3 4
```

Or another option is `grep` where we match the pattern `^.9` (where `^` suggests the start of the string, `.` can be any character followed by 9 i.e. the second character)

```
grep("^.9", p)
#[1] 2 3 4
```

NOTE: Here I am assuming that the OP's vector is `character` class because `numeric` elements don't have `0` padded on the left.

#### data

```
p <- c("34405", "09098424", "6908347", "8900333", "453434")
```

Comment: @RHertel Thanks, I was thinking about posting that as a comment.  Yes, it makes sense to read it as character to get the expected output